getx localization cause the app to refresh and start from sign in page
when I update locals using get.updateLocal() method, I need to stay on same widget and update the language normally but its not the case with me, it rebuild the app and get me to Sign in view.
I tried to change to other solution but the whole project implemented with the Getx methods I can't change it and I couldn't get any solution always the same behavior .
Get.updateLocale(const Locale("ar", "DZ"));

